# Wierd PL SQL invalid cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

When running the following code I get a ORA-01001: invalid cursor Not sure whats going on, I converted it to a procedure and it started happening;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_student_from_class_list (p_stu_id IN NUMBER) 
IS
--Declaring a variable --
    v_date date; 

    --Creating a Cursor to find data from using the p_stu_id paramenter--
    CURSOR enrollments_cursor IS
        SELECT enrollment_date, stu_id, class_id, status
        FROM enrollments 
        WHERE stu_id = p_stu_id;


BEGIN
    /*Changing the date so the code looks for the classes for the student 
    which was entered in the bind variable above for the last 10 years*/
    v_date := add_months(SYSDATE, -120);
    FOR v_enrollment_record IN enrollments_cursor
    LOOP 
--Displays the student's enrollment date, class ID and Current Status for each    class >they taken in last 10 years,from the value which was entered in the bind    variable--
        IF v_enrollment_record.enrollment_date 
        between v_date AND SYSDATE THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enrollment Date: '
            ||v_enrollment_record.enrollment_date
            ||' Class ID: '||v_enrollment_record.class_id
            ||' Status: '||v_enrollment_record.status);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    --Closing the cursor --
    CLOSE enrollments_cursor;

    --Application Express processes the statement--
    COMMIT; 
    --Telling Application Express the procedure has finished--
END p_student_from_class_list;

  --Anonymous Block to run the Procedure--

BEGIN
    p_student_from_class_list(--Student ID--);
END;
```

as I said the code was working when it was got in a procedure but for some reason creating it as a procedure now gives this error. I have been racking my brain trying to work this out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a manual `CLOSE` for a cursor you use as `FOR <record> IN <cursor> LOOP`. You only need to `CLOSE` a cursor you manually `OPEN`ed (and then `FETCH`ed).

Just remove the line:

```
    CLOSE enrollments_cursor;
```

Compare the documentation for [FOR LOOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHCGJAD) and the [OPEN-FETCH-CLOSE pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHCAHJA).

Comment: Wow totally didn't see that! Thank you very much, you a life saver =D

Comment: No problem. Incidentally, you could pass `v_date` as a [parameter to the cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHFAHFE) and use it in the cursor's `WHERE` clause; then you wouldn't need the `IF` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the information :) the vriables were set in the questions due to being asked to input them. Unfortunately date was not being told to be inputted~